# Why its necessary set a static ip to install hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Why its necessary to set a static ip and then put in the /etc/hosts file
put the static ip and host to install hadoop? like this:

```
127..0.1 localhost 
::1      localhost 
192.10.1.20 hadoophost
```

Comment: It all boils down to name resolution. Name resolution is only done during startup of a service or client. Once the name to IP is resolved, then the connection to this IP is established and re-established whenever lost. What happens when a node is rebooted and assigned a new IP? The other nodes will not be able to re-establish connection to the now missing IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general...

> Why its necessary to set a static ip

Because if the machine reboots and acquires a new IP address via DHCP, then your cluster completely breaks.

Other than that, adding an entry to `/etc/hosts` allows the computer to reference other computers and itself by hostname rather than IP address.